# Getting started with Algolia Autocomplete in React (latest) - search field not rendering, how to debug?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, algolia

Followed the instructions from Algolia on implementing AutocompleteJS with React - looks really straight-forward, but i don't know how to debug it. The React component mounts in the DOM, but there's no input field for searching and I don't know what this means, or how to debug it. Does this mean it's unable to find the Algolia source?

Hoping someone with experience in this can point me in the right direction. Been banging my head on the wall for days here, and no amount of documentation has yielded fruit.

Oddly enough I can get InstantSearch working fine.

**Autocomplete Component**

```
import { autocomplete } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js';
import React, { createElement, Fragment, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

// Reference: https://www.algolia.com/developers/autocomplete-library-react/

export function Autocomplete(props) {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const panelRootRef = useRef(null);
  const rootRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const search = autocomplete({
      container: containerRef.current,
      renderer: { createElement, Fragment, render: () => {} },
      render({ children }, root) {
        if (!panelRootRef.current || rootRef.current !== root) {
          rootRef.current = root;

          panelRootRef.current?.unmount();
          panelRootRef.current = createRoot(root);
        }

        panelRootRef.current.render(children);
      },
      ...props,
    });

    return () => {
      search.destroy();
    };
  }, [props]);

  return <div className="border shadow-sm w-[400px]" ref={containerRef} />;
}
```

**Rendering the component:**

```
import { Autocomplete } from "@components/search/autocomplete"
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';
import { getAlgoliaResults } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js';
import Section from "@components/section";

//https://www.algolia.com/blog/ux/replicating-the-algolia-documentation-search-with-autocomplete/

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SEARCH_APPLICATION_ID,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SEARCH_API_KEY
  );

 
function Foo() {
    return (
      <Section>
        <h1>React Application</h1>
        <Autocomplete
          openOnFocus={true}
          getSources={({ query }) => [
            {
              sourceId: 'hits',
              getItems() {
                return getAlgoliaResults({
                  searchClient,
                  queries: [
                    {
                      indexName: 'ccm-en',
                      query,
                    },
                  ],
                });
              },
              templates: {
                item({ item, components }) {
                  return (

                    <div className="some-result">Foo{item.title}</div>
                  )
                },
              },
            },
          ]}
        />
</Section>
    );
  }
  
  export default Foo;
```

p.s. How to find out what the sourceId is? In InstantSearch I used "hits" so I'm assuming it's same here but i'm not sure.

I attached an image of what I'm seeing, when checking source it's just mounting a placeholder, and the submit button.

Thanks for any help.

Specific steps - sourceId, and ensured indexName, SearchClient are correct.

Expecting Autocomplete component to render built-in search box, populated with data from a working Algolia source.